# File management handling

Tags: php, powershell, ftp, jira-rest-api

I am trying to build a solution where I sync a local directory with a ftp server directory. Then the files in the local directory should be send to Jira as a specific issue.

I am trying to understand how I can make script which watches the local directory and when a new file (.pdf) and attachments is created (Look after file id) send a create command to Jira with some data from this newly created file.

Currently i have made the powershell script which reads the FTP and sync's the files to a local directory. Could the rest be made in PHP?

Regards,
Kristian

Comment: Actually all of it can be made with PHP.
for the jira part, you can consume their REST API
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

Answer (score -1):

PHP and PowerShell are both very powerful languages with extensi9on capabilities so you can pretty much do anything you want with both of them. PHP is also available on windows, so I see no objection to writing the whole thing in php.

However, seeing that you already built something in PowerShell, i would recommend that you register the freshly downloaded files in Jira with the same script. Otherwise you would have to build the logic for detecting the changes/additions twice.